# Comparing the same character in VARCHAR and NVARCHAR differs between CP1/CP1252 vs. CP850 based on DB collation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unicode, collation

Here are my two variables:

```sql
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(254) = '5’-Phosphate Analogs Freedom to Operate'
DECLARE @Second NVARCHAR(254) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(254), @First)
```

I have two databases, let's call them "Database1" and "Database2".  Database1 has a default collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS`; Database2 is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.  Both databases have a compatibility level of `SQL Server 2008 (100)`.

I first connect to Database1 and run the following queries:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @First COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    = @Second COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @First COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS 
    = @Second COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS 
    THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END
```

The results are:

```
Equal
Equal
```

Then I connect to Database2 and run the queries; the results are:

```
Equal
Not Equal
```

Note that I have not changed the queries themselves, just the db connection, and I'm specifying the collations to be used rather than allowing them to use the databases' default collations.  Therefore, it's my understanding that the database default collation should not matter, i.e. the results of the queries should be the same regardless of which database I'm connected to.

I have three questions:

1. Why do I get different results when the only thing I change is the database to which I'm connected, given that I've effectively ignored the default database collation by explicitly specifying my own?
2. For the test against Database 2, why does the comparison succeed with the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and fail with the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` collation?  What is the difference between the two collations that account for this?
3. **Most Perplexing:** If the default collation of the database to which I'm connected *does* matter, as it would seem, and the default collation of Database1 is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` (which, remember from my first test resulted in `Equal`, `Equal`) why does the second query, which *explicitly specifies the very same collation* fail (`Not Equal`) when connected to Database2?

Comment: FYI, I am done updating my answer ;-)

Comment: @srutzky -- and what a great answer it is.  Thanks very much for sharing the knowledge and the time it took to answer it.

Comment: The takeaway is: Don't use varchar for anything which may contain characters above 128. If they are computer generated IDs and you can guarantee they don't contains chars > 128, varchar is a space saving especially good for indexed fields. Otherwise, use NVARCHAR.

Comment: @Ben And, if using SQL Server 2012 or newer, and on Enterprise Edition, and _not_ using `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, then Data Compression will, in many (or most perhaps?) cases will store the Unicode string in a sequence of single bytes, making `VARCHAR` not even a space savings. Though I do agree that if one is storing codes, hashes, postal codes, phone numbers, etc, then `VARCHAR` is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply because this is how non-Unicode data works. Non-Unicode data (i.e. 8-bit Extended ASCII) uses the same characters for the first 128 values, but different characters for the second set of 128 characters, based on the Code Page. The character you are testing — `’` — exists in Code Page 1252 but not in Code Page 850.

Yes, the default Collation of the "current" database absolutely matters for string literals and local variables. When you are in a database with a default Collation that uses Code Page 850, that non-Unicode string literal (i.e. a string that is *not* prefixed with `N`) automatically converts the value to an equivalent that does exist in Code Page 850. BUT, that character does indeed exist in Code Page 1252, so there is no need for it to be converted.

So why is it "not equal" when in a database using a Collation associated with Cod Page 1252 between the non-Unicode string and the Unicode string? Because when converting the non-Unicode string into Unicode, another conversion takes place that translates the character into its true Unicode value, which is above decimal value 256.

Run the following in both databases and you will see what happens:

```sql
SELECT ASCII('’') AS [AsciiValue], UNICODE('’') AS [CodePoint];

SELECT ASCII('’' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS [AsciiValue],
        UNICODE('’' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS [CodePoint];

SELECT ASCII('’' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS) AS [AsciiValue],
        UNICODE('’' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS) AS [CodePoint];
```

Results when the "current" database uses a Collation associated with Code Page 850 (all 3 queries return the same thing):

```
AsciiValue    CodePoint
39            39
```

As you can see from the above, specifying `COLLATE` on a string literal is *after the fact* of how that string has already been interpreted with respect to the default Collation of the "current" database.

Results when the "current" database uses a Collation associated with Code Page 1252:

```
-- no COLLATE clause
AsciiValue    CodePoint
146           8217

-- COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AsciiValue    CodePoint
146           8217

-- COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
AsciiValue    CodePoint
39            39
```

But why the conversion from 146 to 8217 if the character is available in Code Page 1252? Because the first 256 characters in Unicode are *not* Code Page 1252, but instead are `ISO-8859-1`. These two Code Pages are mostly the same, but differ by several character in the 128 - 255 range. In the ISO-8859-1 Code Page, those values are control characters. Microsoft felt it better to not waste 16 (or however many) characters on non-printable control characters when the limit was already 256 characters. So they swapped out the control characters for more usable ones, and hence Code Page 1252. But the Unicode group used the standardized ISO-8859-1 for the first 256 characters.

Why does this matter? Because the character you are testing with is one of the lucky few that is in Code Page 1252 but *not* in ISO-8859-1, hence it cannot remain as `146` when converted to NVARCHAR, and gets translated to its Unicode value, which is `8217`. You can see this behavior by running the following:

```sql
SELECT '~' + CHAR(146) + '~', N'~' + NCHAR(146) + N'~';
-- ~’~  ~~
```

Everything shown above explains most of the observed behavior, but does not explain why `@First` and `@Second`, when specified with `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` but running in a database having a default Collation associated with Code Page 1252, register as "Not Equal". If using Code Page 850 translates them to ASCII 39, they should still be equal, right?

This is due to both the sequence of events and the fact that Code Pages are not relevant to Unicode data (i.e. anything stored in `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, and the deprecated `NTEXT` type that nobody should be using). Breaking down what is happening:

1. Start with `@First` being declared and initialized (i.e. `DECLARE @First VARCHAR(1) = '’';`). It is a `VARCHAR` type, hence using a Code Page, and hence using the Code Page associated with the default Collation of the "current" database.
2. The default Collation of the "current" database is associated with Code Page 1252, hence this value is *not* translated to ASCII 39, but exists happily as ASCII 146.
3. Next `@Second` is declared and initialized (i.e. `DECLARE @Second NVARCHAR(1) = @First;` -- no need for explicit `CONVERT` as this is not production code and it will be converted implicitly). This is an `NVARCHAR` type which, as we have seen, has the character, but converts the value from ASCII 146 to Code Point U+2019 (Decimal 8217 = 0x2019).
4. In the comparison, using `@First COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` starts with ASCII 146 as `@First` is `VARCHAR` data using the Code Page specified by the default Collation of the "current" database. But then, since that character does not exist in Code Page 850 (as specified by the Collation used in the `COLLATE` clause) it gets translated into ASCII 39 (as we have seen above).
5. Why didn't `@Second COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` also translate that character to ASCII 39 so that they would register as "Equal"? Because:

   - `@Second` is `NVARCHAR` and does not use Code Pages as all characters are represented in a single character set (i.e. Unicode). So changing the Collation can only change the rules governing how to compare and sort the characters, but will not alter the characters such as what happens sometimes when changing the Collation of VARCHAR data (like in this case of `’`). Hence this side of the comparison is still Code Point U+2019.
   - `@First`, being `VARCHAR` will get implicitly converted into `NVARCHAR` for the comparison. BUT, the `’` character had already been translated into ASCII 39 by the `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` clause, and ASCII 39 is found in Unicode in that same position, either as Decimal 39 or Code Point U+0027 (from `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(2), 39)`).

Resulting comparison is between: *Code Point U+2019* and *Code Point U+0027*
Ergo: **Not Equal**

---

For more info on working with Collations, Encodings, Unicode, etc, please visit: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)